# ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object when mapping data using resources

Tags: laravel

Hi I'm trying to get data and mapping it in resources, but somehow I'm getting error `ErrorException: Trying to get property name of non-object`. I'm already define the relationship in models, but somehow I'm still getting the error.

**User Models**

```
public function shop()
  {
     return $this->hasOne(Shop::class);
  }
```

**Shop Models**

```
public function user()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }
```

And I'm using the resources (ShopCollection) in controller when getting data like this

```
public function index()
    {
        return new ShopCollection(Shop::all());
    }
```

This is how I mapping the data in ShopCollection

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'data' => $this->collection->map(function($data) {
                return [
                    'id_toko' => $data->id,
                    'name' => $data->name,
                    'user' => [
                        'name' => $data->user->name,
                        'email' => $data->user->email,
                        'avatar' => $data->user->avatar,
                        'avatar_original' => $data->user->avatar_original
                    ],
                    'logo' => api_asset($data->logo),
                    ...
                ];
            })
        ];
    }
```

Sorry about my english and thank you for your kind help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ErrorException: Trying to get property name of non-object`

This very common error is also pretty simple to debug: somewhere, one of your variables is `null` but you are still trying to use one of it's property.

It is very likely, from what we can see in your code, that `$data->user` returns `null` at some point.

It's hard to tell when and where since you didn't provided the line, but I'm confident that's the case.

Since your resource is a Collection, Laravel iterates through it.

You can catch the problematic entry by adding:

```php
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'data' => $this->collection->map(function($data) {

                if($data->user == null){
                   dd($data);
                };

                return [
                    'id_toko' => $data->id,
                    'name' => $data->name,
                    'user' => [
                        'name' => $data->user->name,
                        'email' => $data->user->email,
                        'avatar' => $data->user->avatar,
                        'avatar_original' => $data->user->avatar_original
                    ],
                    'logo' => api_asset($data->logo),
                    ...
                ];
            })
        ];
    }
```

---

*This is answer assumes the problem is from `$data->user`. If that's not the case, edit your question with the full error stack trace.*

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @toyi answer I can found out what is the problem.
The reason why I got the error is because some of shops have null user_id. So to handle it I check it first before using it.

This is the code:

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'data' => $this->collection->map(function($data) {
                $user = $data->user ?  [
                    'name' => $data->user->name,
                    'email' => $data->user->email,
                    'avatar' => $data->user->avatar,
                    'avatar_original' => $data->user->avatar_original
                ] : [];
                return [
                    'id_toko' => $data->id,
                    'name' => $data->name,
                    'user' => $user,
                    'logo' => api_asset($data->logo),
                    ...
```